# Regex Match a: b: and c: in [Object a:var b:var c:var];

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have a string: `[Object a:var b:var c:var];`
how can I match `a:`, `b:`, and `c:` with regex?

I've tried: `\[.+\s+(.+:).+\]` but it doesn't  work with a, b, and c it just returns `c:`

Note: `a:` `b:` and `c:` are just placeholders for variables that can change. Also, sometimes there might be just `a:` and `b:` (no c) or `a: b: c: d:`

Comment: Could you be a bit specific ? Will there always be `:var` after the characters you want to match ? Are these characters always letters or could they also contain symbols ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
'[Object a:var b:var c:var]'.match(/(\w+):/g);
["a:", "b:", "c:"]
```